# Boolean value read as string in CakePHP 4 config

Tags: php, cakephp, php-7, cakephp-4.x

I am currently updating my project from CakePHP 3 to CakePHP 4.
A very annoying issue that I'm having is that the `'debug'` value stored in the Config is read as a string, rather than as a boolean.
This causes an error directly in CakePHP's internal classes.

This is the relevant part of `config/app.php`:

```
<?php
return [
    /**
     * Debug Level:
     *
     * Production Mode:
     * false: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown.
     *
     * Development Mode:
     * true: Errors and warnings shown.
     */
    'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),

...
```

In my `.env` file I have this:

```
DEBUG=true
```

This, when used with `filter_var`, evaluates to the boolean value `true`, and should therefore save that in my config array.

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
Argument 2 passed to Cake\Error\ErrorHandler::_displayError() must be of the type boolean, string given, called in /www-data/rebe001/hcms-sme-apps-com-cake4-cake/public/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Error/BaseErrorHandler.php on line 188
```

I have taken a look at the `BaseErrorHandler::handleError` method, and it does read the config to look for the value of the `'debug'` key.
And that value is a string with a value of  `'1'`.

I also have put a `dd()` of the value in my `AppController::initialize` method and also there the value is `'1'`.

I also have tried editing the app.php config file, hardcoding the `true` value:

```
<?php
return [
    /**
     * Debug Level:
     *
     * Production Mode:
     * false: No error messages, errors, or warnings shown.
     *
     * Development Mode:
     * true: Errors and warnings shown.
     */
    //'debug' => filter_var(env('DEBUG', true), FILTER_VALIDATE_BOOLEAN),
    'debug' => true,

...
```

but the outcome doesn't change. I still get the error. So the problem isn't my `.env` file or how the value is being read.
I think the problem lies in how the value is stored in CakePHP's internal config array, or maybe the way it's being retrieved.

The only way I've found to solve the problem is to force the value to a boolean `true` in `AppController::initialize`, but of course I want to avoid this. Adding this line solves the problem so that I can proceed further in my debugging, but I obviously don't want to use this as a permanent solution.

```
Configure::write('debug', true);
```

Has anyone else encountered (and hopefully solved) this?

Comment: It's not something internal to Cake - the standard PhpConfig loader essentially just does an `include "app.php"` as-is. If it's still happening with `'debug' => true,` it's not your env files; at some point you're loading a config value that *is* set it to `'1'`. Try debugging this earlier than in your application  - configs are loaded in bootstrap.php. If you're using the default bootstrap code, note it also loads app_local.php. Check the value directly after each Configure::load to ensure it's set correctly there and you're not unintentionally loading additional config info from other files

Comment: You are actually right! I discovered after further debugging that some values in the config were being rewritten by reading some values from the database, and the value there wasn't correct.

Comment: Glad you found it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the config was indeed being rewritten after it was initially read from config/app.php, and a non-boolean value was being set for the 'debug' key.